# Run shell script downloaded from web

Tags: scripts, dash-shell

I have a .sh script (wget-20121105144134.sh) which I downloaded from the web. The script contains codes to download huge climate data files.

Can you tell me how to run this file on Linux? It is easy for me to run a file which exist in my directory. The file above has been downloaded from the web and how can I add to my current directory or run directly on terminal?

Regards,
Elv.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make it executable.  you can use `chmod +x filename`

or you can right click and select the make executable check box.

Then you can run it by clicking it or even in the terminal with `sh filename.sh` or just `./filename.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just right click the file, select `Properties > Rights` and tick the box called something like "Allow running this file as an executable". After that, you just double click it.